# Best method get Inf from .CSV to specific ID's oder Classes

Tags: jquery, csv, import

I'm making a website for our grocery store and i want to create a product list [- output price tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Glg3w.jpg)

i would like to take all the info from a .csv file. Could someone please help me to find the best method for it?

Comment: I think you need to give more specifics about what you're asking for. First, since you're making a website, there are plenty of ways to get the CSV file, is it served from a server, do you want to upload and process it all in the browser, etc? Then there's the parsing of the file. CSV stands for Comma-Separated Values. How the data is organized is very different from file to file and it's hard to tell what will work for you.

Comment: @Kiren thanks for the fast response! It should be served from the server and load the data on pageload. I thought of something like: (Row 1, Line 2) = ID1, (Row 1, Line 3) = ID2, (Row 1, Line 3) = IDn, ..